# mySQL database missing in mysqlshow

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have just installed the latest MySQL 5.6.17 on my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. I followed all the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html. So far, so good.

But when testing the server, as per point 11 at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/unix-postinstallation.html, the command `bin/mysqlshow` should show a database called "mysql". But it does not appear for me. I can see only the other two.."information_schema" and "test".

MySQL home folder and all subfolders has owner as "root" and group as "mysql". The Data subfolder has owner  "mysql" and group as "mysql".

Any idea why i cannot see the database "mysql"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use : `sudo bin/mysqlshow`

Because of access restrictions with current user account, the `mysql` database will not be shown. Use `sudo` to execute the `bin/mysqlshow` command with root previliges.